# Android Write files

Tags: android, file, bufferedwriter

I write file to sdcard using BufferedWriter.After that I want to overwrite header of file,but other data must be without changes( In the header I must add size of file). So I think I must change position where I need write.

How can I do that?What function should I use?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [RandomAccessFile](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) to access a file, and modify it.